# Delete if exists not working from ansible playbook

Tags: shell, ansible

I am new to Ansible and facing the following issue in one of my playbooks

Ansible playbook task code:

```
- name: Delete existing dist folder
  shell: "[ -d {{ base_path }}/dist ] && rm -rf {{ base_path }}/dist"
```

Output:

```
fatal: [masked.amazonaws.com]: FAILED! => {
"changed": true,
"cmd": "[ -d /home/centos/masked/masked/dist ] && rm -rf /home/centos/masked/masked/dist",
"delta": "0:00:00.098034",
"end": "2018-09-26 20:26:06.940872",
"invocation": {
    "module_args": {
        "_raw_params": "[ -d /home/centos/masked/masked/dist ] && rm -rf /home/centos/masked/masked/dist",
        "_uses_shell": true,
        "argv": null,
        "chdir": null,
        "creates": null,
        "executable": null,
        "removes": null,
        "stdin": null,
        "warn": true
    }
},
"msg": "non-zero return code",
"rc": 1,
"start": "2018-09-26 20:26:06.842838",
"stderr": "",
"stderr_lines": [],
"stdout": "",
"stdout_lines": []
```

If I run this command manually, it works just fine

```
[ -d /home/centos/masked/masked/dist ] && rm -rf 
/home/centos/masked/masked/dist
```

Does anyone have any idea what could be wrong?

Appreciate your responses.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: As Elliot points out, your return code is the problem.  But why do you bother checking whether the directory exists?  If it is NOT a directory, would you still delete it?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Use the `file` module to delete the directory, instead of `shell`:

```
- name: Delete existing dist folder
  file:
    path: "{{ base_path }}/dist"
    state: absent
```

According to [the documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/file_module.html#file-module), it is very close to `rm -rf`:

> If `absent`, directories will be recursively deleted, and files or symlinks will be unlinked. Note that absent will not cause file to fail if the path does not exist as the state did not change.

Comment: Awesome. I don't know why I did not use file, was caught up by the shell command approach. This works and is the better way to do with Ansible. Thanks sduthil.

Answer (score 2):

`non-zero return code`

If the left hand side evaluates to false with your `[ -d {{ base_path }}/dist ]` then you return a non-zero code. Use the three line form instead. Or write a shell script and invoke that instead,

```
if [ -d {{ base_path }}/dist ]; then
    rm -rf {{ base_path }}/dist
fi
```

Comment: I tried and yes the shell script works as well. The 3 line syntext somehow did not work well in Ansible. But finally the approach suggested by sduthil is better as it uses ansible causing one less file to maintain and one less error situation to handle as ansible wont fail for a missing directory. Thanks Elliott anyway.